# For which $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $fy-\lambda$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ for infinitely many $\mathbb{C} \ni \lambda$'s

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f=f(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$,
and for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, denote $F_{\lambda}:=fy-\lambda$.

> Is it possible to characterize all $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $F_{\lambda}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ for infinitely many $\mathbb{C} \ni \lambda$'s?

**Example:** If I am not wrong, $f=x$ is such that $F_{\lambda}=xy-\lambda$ is irreducible for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270687/irreducibility-of-multivariable-polynomials?rq=1) concerning irreducibility of a polynomial in two variables.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: To go just a little further with your example, I think any $f$ which does not depend on $y$ qualifies. And any non-constant $f$ that does not depend on $x$ does not qualify, since $F_\lambda$ is then a polynomial in $y$ only with degree at least 2, and therefore always factors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please, by '$f$ which does not depend on $y$' did you mean that $f$ and $y$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$? (which is equivalent to saying that $f_x \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\{0\}$).

Comment: I mean $f_y = 0$, or given $f=\sum a_{ij} x^i y^j$, we have $j>0 \rightarrow a_{ij}=0$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand; $f_y=0$ implies that $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, and your second condition also says that $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$?

Comment: Yes, I just put it two different ways to try to be clear.

Comment: ok, thanks. If you have a complete answer to my question (I am not sure if your comments include a complete answer, perhaps yes, but some elaboration is needed) then you can write it as an answer, if you like.