# For which $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $\mathbb{C}(x)[y]/(fy-\lambda)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}(t)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f=f(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and denote $F_{\lambda}:=fy-\lambda$.

Assume that for infinitely many $\mathbb{C} \ni \lambda$'s, $F_{\lambda}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, hence $(F_{\lambda})$ is a prime ideal, and then $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(F_{\lambda})$ is an integral domain, so it has a field of fractions, which we will denote by $Q_{\lambda}:=\operatorname{Frac}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(F_{\lambda}))$.

> Is it possible to characterize all $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that
>   $Q_{\lambda}$ is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{C}(t)$, $t$ is a variable, for infinitely many $\mathbb{C} \ni \lambda$'s?

(From those $\lambda$'s for which $F_{\lambda}$ is irreducible, since we which to guarantee that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(F_{\lambda})$ is an integral domain).

**Remarks:**

**(1)** The following is a quotation from the answer of user26857 to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396401/fraction-field-of-fx-yf-isomorphic-to-fxy-f?rq=1):
Let $A$ be a UFD, and $f\in A[Y]$ irreducible with $\deg f\ge 1$. Then the field of fractions of $A[Y]/(f)$ is $K[Y]/(f)$, where $K$ is the field of fractions of $A$.
Here, in my notations: $A=\mathbb{C}[x]$ $f=F_{\lambda}$, so $Q_{\lambda}=\mathbb{C}(x)[y]/(F_{\lambda})$.

**(2)** See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879981/for-which-f-in-mathbbcx-y-fy-lambda-is-irreducible-in-mathbbcx).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb C[t]$?

Comment: Good comment. I have an error in my question, which I will fix in a few seconds/minutes.

Comment: @Bernard, thanks for the edit.