# Irreducibility Over the Rationals (Still Lacking Extra Condition)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime and $g(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ be irreducible modulo $p$. Let $f(x) = g^n(x) + ph(x)$ where $n$ is a positive integer and $h(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$. Given that $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are relatively prime modulo $p$ and the extra condition $deg( h(x))≤ ndeg(g(x))$, I want to show that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$. I tried to start by supposing $f$ is reducible so $f =ab$ but I am not sure how to reach the desired contradiction.

Comment: This looks similar to Eisenstein's criteria.  It might be worth looking at a proof of that.  The title might be more accurate if it were to say Irreducibilty over the rationals, since thst's what you ask to prove.

Comment: Unique factorization in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ tells you that $a$ and $b$ must both be congruent to powers of $g(x)$ modulo $p$. Not sure this helps, but I woud start trying that...

Comment: Seems like we can find infinitely many counter examples: Let $g(x) = x+1,h(x) = x+2$ and $n=2$. $g(x)$ is irreducible $\pmod p$ by definition and since
$$
(x+2) - (x+1)   = 1
$$
they must be coprime $\pmod p$. Now
$$
f(x) = x^2 + (p+2)x + (2p+1)
$$
which has discriminant $p(p-4)$, so reducible over $\mathbb Q$ $\implies$ reducible over $\mathbb Z$ $\implies p(p-4)$ is an integer square. This cannot be true for $p\geq 3$ prime since $\gcd(p,p-4) = \gcd(p,4) = 1$.

Comment: Does the conclusion and the proof below hold if we impose the extra condition deg h(x)≤ n deg(g(x)) ?

Answer (score 4):

if $f=ab$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $ab=g^n$ modulo $p$. Since $g$ is irreducible modulo $p$, we must have $a=g^k$ and $b=g^l$ modulo $p$ with $k+l=n$ and $k,l>0$. So $f=(g^k+pu)(g^l+pv)$, where $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. It follows that
$$f=g^n+p(g^lu+g^kv)+p^2uv=g^n+ph \Rightarrow g^lu+g^kv+puv=h,$$
but then modulo $p$ we would have $g|h$ which is a contradiction.

EDIT: This proof fails in the step where it is claimed that $k,l>0$. Some additional conditions are needed, since one can have a counterexample:

$$f(x)=(1+px)(g+px)=g+p(gx+x+px^2),$$
where $g \neq x$ is any irreducible polynomial, $n=1$, and $h=gx+x+px^2$ which is coprime with $g$.

Comment: There's no guarantee that $a$ and $b$ are not constant modulo $p$, so either $k$ or $l$ might be 0.

Comment: @Contravariant You are right.

Comment: Is the proof valid if we impose the extra condition deg h(x)≤ n deg(g(x))?

Comment: @Homaniac, I don't think that would fix the issue, since if say $l=0$ it is still possible that $u+g^nv$ has a lower degree than $h$ (cancellations with $u$ can happen).

Comment: yea true thanks anyway, I'm thinking if there could be another way to prove, making use of the extra condition imposed:  deg h(x)≤ n deg(g(x))

Comment: As an extra assumption I might consider: *$f$ and $g$ are monic*